# Issue with displaying '=' character in label using LWUIT

Tags: java-me, lwuit

I am creating a video player app wherein I am showing video size. This video size is displayed in a label in this manner. "Size = VIDEO_SIZE". All this text is displayed in one label only.

My problem is that all the text is visible but the '=' character somehow does not get displayed. If I replace this '=' character with ':' then the colon gets displayed correctly. It's a weird behavior.

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the = character to your charset in the bitmap font or better yet use a system font.

Comment: That was the issue. The fonts i used had no = char in the character set. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Please try following, `Size/=VIDEO_SIZE` , you might need to add '/' before the "=" sign. It is called EscapeSquence. Try it out.